# JQuery for many checkboxes hiding/showing corresponding DIVs

Tags: php, jquery, forms

My page has a large amount of form elements on it.  I've got 114 rows of 12 textboxes.  Each row of text boxes has a checkbox that if checked, will hide the row of textboxes.

I'm  was using the following code to toggle the row divs.

```
$(".chk201P").click(function(){
 $("#hide201P").toggle(!this.checked);
 }).triggerHandler('click');

$(".chk201M").click(function(){
 $("#hide201M").toggle(!this.checked);
 }).triggerHandler('click');
```

The above code is for 2 rows.  chk201P and chk201M are the checkboxes and hide201P and hide201M are the DIVs they hide if checked.

**EDIT: After review of comments, I've slightly redesigned the page.  I'm now using the following code to highlight the section I want to hide.  This is based off code I found on the JQuery API site.

```
$("form input:checkbox").wrap('<span></span>').parent().parent().siblings('.typentry').css({background:"yellow", border:"1px red solid"});
```

Following that logic, I'm attempting to use the following to make the DIV hide and come back based on the checkbox, but its not working.

```
$("form input:checkbox").click(function() {
$(this.parent().parent().siblings('.typentry')).toggle(!this.checked);
```

}).triggerHandler('click');

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with the code?

**End EDIT

Given the amount of rows and text boxes, is there an easier way to write the JQuery instead of duplicating the above code 46 more times for the corresponding data?

[Old Example page](http://www.montco911.com/Forms/selectbeta5.php) 
[New Example page](http://www.montco911.com/Forms/selectbeta6.php)

Comment: Can you post an example of your HTML structure?

Comment: Updated question and posted new example page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved....

```
$("form input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var dataID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#hide" + dataID).toggle(!this.checked);
    $("#nor" + dataID).toggle(this.checked);
    //return false;
}).triggerHandler('click');
```

To explain...

Each of the 94 checkboxes are generated by a loop, pulling info from a DB.  Each loop pulls that particular rows ID.  The checkboxes are given names that match those IDs.  In my case, its 201P through 247P and 201M through 247M.  The text boxes that I want to hide are given an ID of "hide+ID" or hide201P,etc.  The nor is the div I'm showing when hiding the other and its given an ID of nor201P, etc.  When the checkbox is checked, the hide DIV is hidden and the nor DIV is shown.

Thanks to Bob for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just apply the same function to every checkbox ? If I understand correctly, you want to hide the parent row ?

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('tr').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

This code is not tested, but I hope it gives you an idea.

Edit: Added the '$(this).is(':checked')' so it would only hide the row is the checkbox was checked.

Editted after the code example:
Ok I just looked at your code. Please explane me one thing because I can't figure it out. You build the whole table out of divs and spans. Why is that ? Why not just use a normal table ? (I know there are a tons of reasons for it but I wonder what yours is). But what really stunned me is the fact that at the bottom of your page, you do use a table to align 2 anchor tags next to eachother. Why not also use a div here ?

Furthermore I would like to advise you to take a second look at your HTML. If you want to use jQuery a lot, it's easier to put the affected dom elements of 1 action in the same div. I'll post an example of this below. This is because it is easier to find this elements with the selectors.

```
Example: (wrong way)
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text">
</div>

(right way, atleast for me)
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

I hope I have informed you enough. If you have any questions. Please feel free to ask ^^.

Comment: I'm rather new to JQuery so forgive me.  When you say apply the same function, do you mean this code should go in each checkbox or this code will should apply to each checkbox if loaded on Document Ready?

Comment: The example code I used above won't work on your site. That's because you have an other HTML layout then the one this piece of code was written for. Please read the part I edited.

Comment: The page was originally built using tables and I was having trouble getting the formatting to look the way I wanted.  The links at the bottom are still in a table because I haven't switched them over yet.  I'm trying to get functionality down before I worry about the little stuff.

Comment: Please look at http://api.jquery.com/find/ and http://api.jquery.com/parent/ . With those 2 jQuery functions you will be able to do what you want.

Comment: Also, the checkboxes are a late addition due to new functionality they want.

Comment: wouldn't putting the checkbox inside the same div as the textboxes I want to hide also hide the checkboxes?

Comment: Nah, something like the following will work. $(this).parent('div').find('input[type=text]').toggle();

Comment: If the inputs are within an enclosing DIV, but in separate SPANs, would it make a difference?